# ERROR: INPUT function reported 'ERROR: Invalid date value' while processing WHERE clause

Tags: sas

In proc sql where clause when i use this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCTps.png)

```
where input(put(datecolumn, 8.)yymmdd10.)>='01jan2021'd and 
and input(put(datecolum,8.),yymmdd8.)<=datepart(differentdatecolumn)
```

Im getting
ERROR: INPUT function reported 'ERROR: Invalid date value' while processing WHERE clause.
datecolumn is numeric sample value='20201003'

Comment: Please show the actual lines from the SAS log so that the code run and the errors reported by SAS are clearer.

Comment: Are you sure that DATECOLUMN actually has values like 20,201,003?  What if it actually has the number 22,191 instead but is using the `yymmddn8.` format so it prints as 20201003?

Comment: the datecolumn is numeric datevalue '20201003' which is yymmdd8.

Comment: If the stored values are actually already the number of days from 1960 (like 22,191) then you don't need to use the PUT() and INPUT() functions to try to convert the integers that look to humans like dates into dates.  `where datecolumn >='01jan2021'd ...`

Comment: Perhaps the issue is the DIFFERENTDATECOLUMN variable?  Are you sure that it is numeric and contains the number of seconds since 1960?  Does the variable have a format attached to it?  If so what format?

Comment: "Differencedatecolumn" is datetime18. format

Comment: Please add a sample dataset (a data step with input datalines) that with this code generates the error shown.

Comment: THIS IS HOW THE VALUES ARE IN THE TABLE 'DATECOLUMN'=20210422
'DIFFERENTDATECOLUMN'='30MAY21:00:00:00'

Comment: attached image how the date values look

Comment: How the values look in some GUI screen is not that helpful.  Strings and numbers displayed as strings cannot be distinguished.  Also there not be any difference different between a number like 20,201,003 and a date like 03OCT2020 that is being displayed using the YYMMDDN8. format.

Comment: how can i address the error

Answer (score 1):

You have several syntax errors in the code shown so I'm surprised that's the only error. Using BETWEEN will simplify your code and makes it easier to debug since you're not replicating your calculations/formulas.

1. Missing comma in the INPUT function
2. Duplicate AND

```
where input(put(datecolumn, 8.), yymmdd10.) between '01jan2021'd and 
datepart(differentdatecolumn);
```

Comment: code:PROC SQL;
 CREATE TABLE X AS 
  SELECT distinct B.MEM, C.* FROM table1 A JOIN
   Table2 B ON A.MEM=B.MEM JOIN 
   Table3  C ON B.X= C.X JOIN
   PRJ.Table4 D ON D.MEM=B.MEM
  WHERE C.column='XXX' and C.column2 in ('XYZ','ABC') 
   and yearcolumn=2021 AND input(put(datecolumn,8.),yymmdd8.)>='01jan2021'd
   and input(put(datecolumn,8.),yymmdd8.)<=datepart(D.different_date_column);

Comment: ERROR: INPUT function reported 'ERROR: Invalid date value' while processing WHERE clause.
ERROR: INPUT function reported 'ERROR: Invalid date value' while processing WHERE clause.
ERROR: INPUT function reported 'ERROR: Invalid date value' while processing WHERE clause.
ERROR: INPUT function reported 'ERROR: Invalid date value' while processing WHERE clause.
ERROR: INPUT function reported 'ERROR: Invalid date value' while processing WHERE clause.
ERROR: Limit set by ERRORS= option reached.  Further errors for this INPUT function will not be printed.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have a value that cannot be converted to a valid date.
Like 20,201,000 where the day of the month is zero. Or 20,210,229 where the day of the month is past the end of the month.

For example if you have data like this:

```
data have ;
  input date ;
cards;
20210322
20210332
;
```

And try to use your INPUT(PUT()) function sandwich in a where clause you get that error message.

```
711   data want;
712    set have;
713    where input(put(date,z8.),yymmdd8.) > '01JUN2021'd ;
714   run;

ERROR: INPUT function reported 'ERROR: Invalid date value' while processing WHERE clause.
NOTE: There were 0 observations read from the data set WORK.HAVE.
      WHERE INPUT(PUT(date, Z8.), YYMMDD8.)>'01JUN2021'D;
NOTE: The data set WORK.WANT has 0 observations and 1 variables.
```

You can easily look for the observations that have this issue by just checking if you have a non-missing value and the transformation function returns a missing value.

```
data check;
  set have;
  if not missing(date) and missing(input(put(date,z8.),??yymmdd8.));
run;
```

Comment: the values are valid as i mentioned the sample value='20210322'

Comment: How do you know that you have valid date values?  If the values are stored as integers like `20,210,322` or as strings like `'20210322'` what is preventing some of them from containing values that do not represent a real date?

Comment: I hardly have 70 values i looked up manually.

Comment: If your variable's values are already dates then don't convert them into strings and back into numbers. Just use them directly.

Comment: the variable values are in numeric function with a value '20210322'

Comment: Note that SAS only has two data types, fixed length strings and floating point numbers.  So to tell whether your "date" variable has date values or just integers that look like dates to humans you need check what format is attached to the variable.  Or look at the values without any format attached.

Comment: the values are integers they look the same as date as I provided the value sample above

Comment: I updated the answer with a more detailed example of how to find the offending values.

Comment: I tried the code above you provided to check If there are any missing values. i didn't find any

Comment: The other method to discover the value that is generating the error is the process of elimination.  Run your code on half of the data.  Based on whether or not it gets the error run your code on half of the half, etc. Until you find the example data point that generates the message.  Then you can try to understand what it is about that data point that is causing the error.

Comment: The log will actually indicate the errors and puts them in the log. Posting the actual log helps not just the error message.